# Databind Two Properties Using Linq

Tags: asp.net

I think my linq query is yielding no results because the "Stock" object is not being instantiated. Any help here would be welcome!

In my class:

```
   public class Stock
{
    public List<string> Names { get { return NamesList(); } }
    public List<int> Prices { get { return PriceList(); } }

        private List<int> PriceList()
    {

        Random random = new Random();
        List<int> stockPriceList = new List<int>();
        stockPriceList.Add(random.Next(100, 220));
        stockPriceList.Add(random.Next(1000, 5365));
        return stockPriceList;
    }

    private List<string> NamesList()
    {
        List<string> stockNames = new List<string>();
        stockNames.Add("CBA");
        stockNames.Add("ANZ");
         return stockNames;
    }

}
```

In my databinding method. Lync query yields no results.

```
private void bindPriceList()
    {

        List<Stock> stockList = new List<Stock>();

        rptPriceList.DataSource = stockList.Select(s => new { Name = s.Names, Price = s.Prices });

        rptPriceList.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class RepeaterExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.bindPriceList();
        }
    }

    private void bindPriceList()
    {
        var stock1 = new Stock { Name = "CBA", Price = "12.99" };
        var stock2 = new Stock { Name = "ANZ", Price = "13.99" };
        rptPriceList.DataSource = new List<Stock> { stock1, stock2 };
        rptPriceList.DataBind();
    }
}

public class Stock
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPriceList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><%# Eval("Name") %> - <%# Eval("Price") %></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: That would work but not quite what I was after. I want to keep the 2 lists abstracted in the stock class and keep the bind method uncluttered.

Comment: How do you imagine you will bind two different lists to a single repeater which can only be bound to ONE IEnumerable\IList.And you can still abstract the binding logic,just create a new class and a method in it the returns List<Stock>